# Entity Framework 4.0 with Linq

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Comment> GetUserComments()
{
    return List<Comment>
    {
        new Comment
        {
            CommentFor = "ee",
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            CommentText = "aaaa",
            Location = new Location
            {
                Name = "Location Name",
                Country = new Country
                {
                    Name="Israel"
                },
                State=new State { Name="TelAviv" }
            }
        } 

    };
}
```

Can you help me correct Linq query for that?

I need to take value from database using Entity Framework 4.
I did like this

```
         public IEnumerable<Models.Comment> GetUserComments()
    {
         var comment = (from u in context.Comments
                       where u.UserID == userId
                       select new Comment
                       {
                           //Location = context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.locationid == u.LocationID).name,
                           Location = (from l in context.Locations
                                       where l.LocationID == u.LocationID
                                       select new Location
                                       {
                                           Name = l.Name,
                                           State = (
                                                 from s in context.States
                                                 where (s.StateID == l.StateID)
                                                 select new State { Name  = s.Name }
                                                 ).FirstOrDefault()

                                       }
                                       ).FirstOrDefault(),
                           CommentFor = "bs",
                           DateAdded = u.DateAdded,
                           CommentText = u.CommentText
                       }
                    ).ToList();
                       }
```

getting error like:

> The entity or complex type 'CGWeb.Models.Repositories.Comment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Please tell me where my mistake i had done

Comment: And please take some time to properly format your code (see my update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u.Location` should be `Location`.

Comment: i did like this ..that problem solved now .thanks for quick replay..but still have other problem. like this: The entity or complex type 'CGWeb.Models.Repositories.Comment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 2):

```
                   select new Comment
                   {
                       u.Location //<- remove the u.
```

Comment: ok. that is one issue .that solved now ... but now error getting like.The entity or complex type 'CGWeb.Models.Repositories.Comment' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: If "Comment" is an entity from your model you will get this problem. you have to use anonymous types or unmapped types in your projections.

Comment: ok.. can you specify what  you mean by "anonymous types" ..here what solution needed..?please share

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var comment = (from u in context.Comments
                           where u.UserID == userId
                           select new Comment
                           {
                               Location = context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.LocationID==u.LocationID).Name,                                        
                               CommentFor = "Bb",
                               DateAdded = u.DateAdded,
                               CommentText = u.CommentText
                           }
                        ).ToList();
```